# May I use 2 aggregators in one Spring Integration flow?

Tags: java, aggregate, spring-integration

I need to send message to 3 services, and aggregate result at the end.
This is easy via `publish-subscribe-channel->service-activator(s)->aggregator`.

The problem appears when one of the services is in reality 2 calls to other services. At this point I want to introduce additional `publish-subscribe-channel` and aggregator.

E.g.

```
publish-subscribe-channel1 -> service-activator group1 -> aggregator1
  \/-> service call -> publish-subscribe-channel2 -> service-activator group2 -> aggregator2
```

As a result `aggregator2` doesn't group message(send them out one by one).

`Aggregator1` gets results from `aggregator2` and send out message without waiting for messages from service-activator group 1.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your `publish-subscribe-channel` should have `apply-sequence="true"`. Of course, if you don't use custom `correlation` and `release` strategies.

With `apply-sequence="true"` the Framework populates standard `correlation` `MessageHeaders` and they are stored in the `Stack`: the nested aggregator gets deal with `correlation` of its scope and pop them from stack to be ready for the outer aggregation.

And the nested `aggregator` should send its result to the input channel of outer `aggregator`.
For the last one it will look like just a result of a service.